# canopen_chain_node and init device

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to init vcan0?

I need to use can::SocketCANInterface ?

```
can::Frame msg1;
msg1.id = 1;
msg1.data = {1,2,3,4};
  const string driv("vcan0");
  can::SocketCANInterface driver;

  printf("init = %d\n",driver.init(driv, true));
  printf("rec = %d\n",driver.recover());
  printf("state = %d\n",(int)driver.getState().isReady());
  printf("send = %d\n",driver.send(msg1));
```

Output:

```
init = 1
rec = 0
state = 0
send = 0
```

And how to send messages using a dictionary in canopen_chain_node .

canopen_chain_node configured correctly and launched.

Please, help to understand, I am a beginner to ROS.

[My .yaml file](https://github.com/Dizett/roscanopen_eds/blob/master/forklift_base.yaml)

Does anyone have an example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282855/canopen_chain_node-and-init-device/) by [Dizett](https://answers.ros.org/users/33703/dizett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How to init vcan0?

For setting up vcan, just follow the directions in the [driver documentaion, section 6.4](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt)

> And how to send messages using a dictionary in canopen_chain_node .

You cannot send message using a dictionary.
But you can use the (currently undocumented) set_object service to write to the (remote) node object dictionary.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dizett](https://answers.ros.org/users/33703/dizett/) on 2018-02-22**:
I don't understand. How do I use canopen_chain_nod to send commands to a device? И как получать сообщения от устройства? Thank You!

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2018-02-22**:
You have to interact with the corresponding objects of the dictionary. This is device-specific. In most cases these dictionaries are standardized as device profiles.
Please stick to English.

**Comment by [Dizett](https://answers.ros.org/users/33703/dizett/) on 2018-02-22**:
How i can  to interact with the corresponding objects of the dictionary? I Need to use the topics? I need something to prescribe in .a yaml file for this? Thank You!

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2018-02-22**:
Just configure and initialize `canopen_chain_node` and use the provided services.

**Comment by [Dizett](https://answers.ros.org/users/33703/dizett/) on 2018-02-22**:
[My .yaml file](https://github.com/Dizett/roscanopen_eds/blob/master/forklift_base.yaml) this is a sufficient configuration?

If i add

```
node1:
  publish: ["1003sub0!"]
```

do I have to subscribe to the topic 1003sub0 to receive messages from the device?
Or I need to publish in topic for the device?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2018-02-22**:
The canopen_chain_node does not care if someone subscribes to the topics. It will just read the object (per SDO or PDO) periodically and publish it at the SYNC/update rate.

**Comment by [Dizett](https://answers.ros.org/users/33703/dizett/) on 2018-02-22**:
an example on Python

```
self.steer_controller = self.network.add_node(0x01 ,'/home/turtle1/ros/base_control/eds/phyPS409Y.eds')
steer_controller.sdo[0x6411][2].raw = value
```

**Comment by [Dizett](https://answers.ros.org/users/33703/dizett/) on 2018-02-22**:
Does it have to look like this in ros?

```
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int16>("node2_6411sub2",20);
  ...
  std_msgs::Int16 a;
  pub.publish(a);
```

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2018-02-22**:
`canopen_chain_node` does not expose any code API, only the generic topics (read) and the get/set_objects services. If you need more, you have to extend the chain node or use `canopen_master` directly.
`canopen_chain_node` is mostly meant as base for profile implementations like canopen_motor_node.

**Comment by [Dizett](https://answers.ros.org/users/33703/dizett/) on 2018-02-22**:
I don't understand.So how do I communicate with the device using dictionaries? Is there an example?
Please, help me!

**Comment by [Dizett](https://answers.ros.org/users/33703/dizett/) on 2018-03-14**:
How to send data using canopen_master or canopen_motor_node?